# How do I stop the react-select input dropdown menu from opening when click the isClearable icon (mobile only)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events, react-select

I made this very simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-codesandboxer-example-dl6ug?file=/example.js&codemirror=1) to show my problem.

[image]

When I click the 'x' icon that appears after adding `isClearable` to the Select component, it both clears the selection AND it also opens the dropdown. I do not want to open the dropdown menu, but I cannot figure out how to stop it. Any ideas?

This problem only exists on mobile browsers. The clear function works as expected on desktop browsers. To see the codesandbox on mobile, open Chrome devtools and click the "toggle device toolbar" button.

EDIT: Since I haven't received a response yet (22 hours), here are some more details. [This discussion](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/532) most closely resembles my issue. They discuss the cause may be due to the react-tap-event-plugin.

I have tried using the react-fastclick package since I thought it may be a delayed tap (long-pressing in mobile does not open menu).

I have tried adding a div around the `Select` component with the attribute `onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); }}`

I have tried adding a dummy div, and calling `document.getElementById("dummy").focus()` at the end of the `onChange` event in the `Select` component.

EDIT 2: If you add an event break-point for the `touchend` event, click the 'x' causing the script to pause, then press F8 (resume script), the menu will not open. There must be some sort of delayed tap happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hacky solution. I set `pointer-events: null` in the css for 50 milliseconds at the end of my `onChange` event function attribute within the `Select` component. If someone knows a less hacky way of making this work, please let me know!

```js
temporarilyDisable = () => {
  const elementToDisable = document.getElementById('selectComponentID');
  const wait = ms => new Promise((r, j)=>setTimeout(r, ms))
  elementToDisable.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: none")
  let prom = wait(50).then(() => elementToDisable.setAttribute("style", "pointer-events: all"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this property to the Select component:

```
openMenuOnClick={false}
```

Works for me, hope it does to you too.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-silence-d4hfm?file=/src/App.js)

Still not working well at least, it will give you hint how to modify the default behavior.

Comment: Since you added `menuIsOpen=false` the dropdown menu no longer opens when clicked. I still intend to use that feature, so this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got some code like this

```
<Select
    isClearable
    options={options}
    //..
/>
```

Then you have the same bug I had.
The "isClearable" flag needs a value.

```
<Select
    isClearable={true}
    options={options}
    //..
/>
```

Hope it helps. ♥